# Power on button test for shutting down using c

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the below app when ever I press cpu`` power on button  my application as to pause for few min like 5 min for that I used below app.the problem is I used sleep(300000) for stoping few min but the operation is not performing whenever I press power button please let me know if any on

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHUTDOWN_TEST
FILE *fp;

BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType )
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    switch( fdwCtrlType )
    {
    // Handle the CTRL-C signal.
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
        Beep( 750, 300 );
        return( TRUE );

        // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit.
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        Beep( 600, 200 );
        printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
        return( TRUE );

        // Pass other signals to the next handler.
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        Beep( 900, 200 );
        printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
        return FALSE;

    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        Beep( 1000, 200 );
        printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
        return FALSE;

    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:


        printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
        while(1)
        {    
            Sleep(300000);
        }

        Beep( 750, 500 );

        return FALSE;

    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    fp = (fopen("C:\\shutdown.txt","w"));

#ifdef SHUTDOWN_TEST
    if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) )
    {
        printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" );
        printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" );
        printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" );
        printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" );

        while( 1 ){
            printf("I am running\n");
            Sleep(3000) ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
#else
    if (pid = fork())
    {
        if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) )
        {
            printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" );
            printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" );
            printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" );
            printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" );

            while( 1 ){
                //  printf("I am running\n");
                //  Sleep(3000) ;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question needs to be edited, as apparently some of the text got cut off so it is unclear what you are asking.  Please be as specific as possible about exactly what behavior you are expecting, and what result you are actually getting when identifying your problem.  I am also adding the `winapi` tag to your post - correct tagging will increase your chances of getting a better answer.  I also deleted the commented-out code in your post, as it is not relevant. Please visit the FAQs section, the How To Ask section, and this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: the above app while i am running if i press ctrl-c and ctrl-break event the signal i can see in .exe running because those are software interrupts sigint and sigabrt but when i press cpu power button for CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT its should wait for few minutes is there any windows api for pausing,

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the System shutdown can not be done inside such a handler. Since Windows Vista there is a new API.

Use [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can use GetConsoleWindow to get the requested window handle.

Read this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the changes since Vista.

Comment: i am using windows 7 64 bit machine is there any possibility to pause the application for few minutes when shutting down

Comment: where you added the link

Comment: I sawed the link is there any possibility to pause the application for 5 min while shutting down.

Comment: can we do it for console application

Comment: i am trying to do for console app

Comment: can you please send me if any examples are there using ShutdownBlockReasonCreate in c for win7 32 bit